# Adding in major_label_orientation value makes chart blank

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm creating a bar chart using Bokeh. My chart renders fine initially, but when I add in the following line (to rotate the X labels):

`p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 1.2`

The chart becomes blank. Why is this occurring?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this occurred because my x axis labels were too long. When I shortened the labels, the chart reappeared with the rotated labels. (Increasing the height of the figure might be another way to solve this issue.)

Comment: Playing with the related [Bokeh GitHub Issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/12069) you are right. Increasing the figure also works.